# I cannot get the InputOutput direction to work for a stored procedure on Azure Sql

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I have created the following stored procedure in Azure SQL.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Composite_Shop_GetNextOrdreNo]
    @OrderPrefix NVARCHAR(50) OUTPUT,
    @IsTestMode int = 0
AS
    DECLARE @NextOrderNumber int

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 [OrderPrefix] 
                   FROM [dbo].[Composite_Shop_OrderNumber] 
                   WHERE [OrderPrefix] = @OrderPrefix)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Composite_Shop_OrderNumber] (OrderPrefix) 
        VALUES (@OrderPrefix)
    END

    UPDATE [dbo].[Composite_Shop_OrderNumber] WITH (READCOMMITTEDLOCK)
    SET @NextOrderNumber = Number = Number + 1
    WHERE [OrderPrefix] = @OrderPrefix

    SELECT @OrderPrefix = @OrderPrefix +  REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(RTRIM(CONVERT(nvarchar(50), @NextOrderNumber)))) + CONVERT(nvarchar(50), @NextOrderNumber)

    RETURN
```

No matter what I try from C# I have not succeeded in giving it one parameter and getting it out again modified.

Intutively I would assume this should work but it don't.

```
var param = new SqlParameter("@OrderPrefix",SqlDbType.NVarChar);
param.value = "test";
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

When I check the param after its been executed its the same as it was when sending it in.

I assume there must be something I have missed.

Comment: wrapped in a SqlCommand set as Stored Procedure and commandtext set to the stored procedure name.

Comment: Have you tried using `ParameterDirection.Output` ? Also: I would **always** specify a **length** for my `NVarChar` parameters: `var param = new SqlParameter("@OrderPrefix", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50); param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;`

Comment: if i use .Output it wont work as it also need an input on the first parameter. And also tried with length on nvarchar.